# A (somewhat) picky subscript notation?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

This is probably a weird question, but I will ask it anyway. I am trying to find a certain syntax for the following notation. I have

[image]

However, I want to write j = i +1.

These do not look good:

[image]

[image]

A comma in between them also does not work in this context. Is there any way to make this look better or I am just being too picky?

Comment: Why does a comma `,` not work in this context? What about a semi-colon `;`. This sounds very subjective.

Comment: Not TeX-related; this is a question purely about mathematical notation standards. Voting to close.

Comment: the space in your second image looks weirdly large, but as you have shown no code, it is hard to correct your code. Try `X_{i\,i+1}`

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your claim that a "comma in between them also does not work in this context." (Maybe you should explain the context, so that people will have a chance to come up with something more suitable.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
$X_{ij}$ vs.\ $X_{i,j+1}$
\end{document}
```